# After copying over files in file system, Android Studio doesn't show those files

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a new project in AndroidStudio and I am trying to copy files from an existing project to the new one.

I was able to copy many of the xml files, but for some reason the .java files and the AndroidManifest.xml file don't show up in AndroidStudio after being copied.

Here is the screenshots of my AndroidStudio project and my file system containing my AndroidManifest.xml file and my .java files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you restarted and tried all the basics? This happens to me sometimes, invalidating caches helped.

Comment: Well, if you copy files into random locations, the IDE will ignore them. You did not put the files where Android Studio is expecting them. `src/` in Android Studio does not mean what `src/` did in Eclipse.

Comment: @hitch.united yes you are correct in that. Of course I restarted - but what is the next thing I should try?

Comment: @CommonsWare you always come to the rescue. :) Where is the right spot to put that stuff?

Comment: @Genadinik Is the 3rd picture the one where you copied files to? I don't see them

Comment: @hitch.united the 3rd picture is where the AndroidManifest is

Comment: Probably inside the `main` sourceset, though there are other possibilities. If your objective is for your new code to live alongside your existing code, see where your existing code lives, then put your new code in directories in relationship to that existing code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good point - thank you. Btw, are you still focusing on promoting your book? I remember you mentioned it some time ago

Comment: Yes, I still have [a book](https://commonsware.com/Android). Among other things, it explains the directory structure of Android Studio projects. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to help you get promotion for the book. I have a big YouTube channel that partly covers apps - if you want, I can interview you